# Sending a character to the Arduino serial port using Python's Pyserial

Tags: python, serialization, matplotlib, serial-port

I have setup an Arduino to send data when it receives an 'S' byte. This works in the Arduino serial monitor. However, I am plotting the data on Python, using Pyserial to contact the serial port. Here is my Arduino sketch to make clear what I am saying:

```
#include <eHealth.h>


unsigned long time;
unsigned long interval = 8;
byte serialByte;

// The setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

// The loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    serialByte = Serial.read();
    if(serialByte == 'S'){  
      while(1){
        float ECG = eHealth.getECG();
        time = time + interval;
        Serial.print(time);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(ECG, 3); 
        Serial.println("");

        if(Serial.available()>0){
          serialByte = Serial.read();
          if (serialByte == 'F') break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  delay(interval);
}
```

As I said this works fine. But on Python when I try this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600)
ser.write(bytearray('S','ascii'))
```

or this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600)
ser.write('S')
```

The arduino doesn't recieve it for some reason and the data doesn't flow through the serial port to Python. I do not know the problem. As you can see I have tried converting to bytes and it still doesn't work.

Here is my full Python code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QTAgg
import matplotlib.figure as mfig
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui, PyQt4.QtCore as core
import collections
import time
import random

import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600)
ser.write('S')


refreshMillis = 8
N = 200
xs = collections.deque(maxlen=N)
ys = collections.deque(maxlen=N) 

app = gui.QApplication([])

fig = mfig.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim([0,5])
# ax.title("Arduino Electrocardiogram")
ax.set_xlabel("Time (ms)")
ax.set_ylabel("Voltage (V)")
line2D, = ax.plot(xs,ys)
canvas.show()


def process_line():
    line = ser.readline()
    data = map(float,line.split(" "))
    xs.append(data[0])
    ys.append(data[1])
    line2D.set_data(xs,ys)
    print data
    xmin, xmax = min(xs),max(xs)
    if xmin == xmax:
        ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmin+1])
    else:
        ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
    canvas.draw()

    zipString = zip(xs,ys)
    f = open("plot_store","w")
    for line in zipString:
        f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in line) + "\n")
    f.close()




timer = core.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(process_line)
timer.start(refreshMillis)

app.exec_()

ser.flush()
ser.close()
```

Comment: A shot in the dark: Have you tried calling `ser.flush()` immediately after calling `ser.write('S')`?

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, didn't make a difference however, I just the figure window popping up and axes but no values plotted.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot.  For further debugging, I recommend creating a simpler example, with all the Qt and Matplotlib stuff removed.  Get the I/O figured out with a simple script before worrying about the plotting and GUI stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This caught me out when I started with Arduino serial. When you open the serial connection (e.g. via Python) the Arduino resets, missing the next few characters.

I usually do something like:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
time.sleep(3)
ser.write('Hello world')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks... this seems to have solved it for me. The puzzler is the Arduino (Nano) receives a "M-x" character when Serial() is called. After the sleep everything seems fine. Any ideas?

Comment: If you leave auto-reset enabled then you'll get garbage both ways just after you open serial. Best options are to either deal with that in software (by ignoring those bytes) or disable auto-reset like this... http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190218024201/http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

Comment: An alternative to using `time.sleep()` is to wait for a startup message over the serial port from the Arduino. For example, `while not ser.read_until().decode().strip() == 'Listening.': pass`